# How to connect android application with OLA API?

Tags: java, android, api

I am building an app using Ola API. I am new to android development and have never used any external API. Can someone please show how to connect with Ola API and do some basic functions in android that are provided by Ola API like -

- Login the user
- Book the cab
- Cancel the cab
- Logout the user

I refereed Ola API (https://developers.olacabs.com/docs) but it seems confusing for a beginner please help. 
Some code examples would be better. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

OLA API uses JSON so I think you should use [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) A type-safe HTTP client for Android and Java.
as it considered the best library for handling REST APIs.

to get start with Retrofit see [this](https://github.com/square/retrofit/wiki/Retrofit-Tutorials) and [this](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client)

Comment: Thank you for responding. :)